# PHP get absolute path without following symlinks

Tags: php, filesystems, realpath

How do I get the absolute path to a file, without following symlinks.

E.g.

```
/path/to/some/file
/path/to/some/link -> /path/to/some/file
/path/to/some/directory/
```

My current working directory is `/path/to/some/directory/` and I go `realpath('../link)` it returns `/path/to/some/file`.

*(I know `realpath` is supposed to work this way)*

Is there a function instead of `realpath` that would return `/path/to/some/link`

Comment: Assuming that PHP will properly handle `/path/to/some/directory/../link` I doubt that there is a function out there. I may be wrong, but your best bet would be to write your own.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `__DIR__ . '/../link'`?

Comment: @Jack no because the path is not relative to the PHP file.

Answer (score 3):

[David Beck](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php#71334) wrote a solution that cleans up the relative path components without accessing the actual file system in the comments section of the PHP manual. Alas, he forgot to add a `return` statement to the function, but otherwise it seems to work great if this is what you need. Also works with URLs.

```
function canonicalize($address)
{
    $address = explode('/', $address);
    $keys = array_keys($address, '..');

    foreach($keys AS $keypos => $key)
    {
        array_splice($address, $key - ($keypos * 2 + 1), 2);
    }

    $address = implode('/', $address);
    $address = str_replace('./', '', $address);

    return $address;
}

$url = '/path/to/some/weird/directory/../.././link';
echo canonicalize($url); // /path/to/some/link
```

Comment: I have tried a similar function to this, but it does find the absolute path from a relative one (e.g. `../link` just returns `..`).

Comment: Works well but doesn't in cases when you have `../` in "multiple places". Example: `/path/to/some/weird/directory/../../../link../` or `/path/to/some/weird/directory/../../../link..`

Answer (score 2):

there's also `getcwd();` which I use quite often. Syntactically simpler.

Comment: `chdir($dir);echo getcwd();` this is far better than a user defined path resolution function. Thank you!